# Is it possible to modify scrapy Response object in middleware?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I scrape some data from several EU sites and find that sometimes my calls to `response.xpath()` brokes text. For instance, I found that html entities like `"& amp;" &#164` and other similar translated into broken bytes like `\x92` or `\xc3` etc.
I found some working solution - escape html entities before calls to xpath method (using lxml lib). Looks Like this:

```
body_str = str(response.body, response._body_declared_encoding())
unescaped_body = html.unescape(body_str)
response = response.replace(body=unescaped_body)
```

It seems to work fine for me if such code called immediately at start of callback for processing response.

What I'm trying to do now is to move this code into Spider Middleware, to use this approach for each request or in another spider etc. But problem is that this code doesn't modify response object inside

```
def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
```

Seems that `response = response.replace(...)` creates new local variable response, which isn't used elsewhere. 
And my question is in title: can I modify response object inside spider middleware or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is better to use a [`Downloader Middleware`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) with the `process_response` method and return a `Response` object.

```
...
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    ...
    body_str = str(response.body, response._body_declared_encoding())
    unescaped_body = html.unescape(body_str)
    new_response = response.replace(body=unescaped_body)
    return new_response
```

Comment: Thank's. You are right and Downloader Middleware is perfect to replace Response object. Unfortuanlly my certain solution didn't work right there because in middleware i can't use ` _body_declared_encoding()` (returns None) and response.body is raw and possible still gziped bytes object. I will learn more about this and try to find new solution. Many thanks again cause you answer my in tittle question

Comment: I get error `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments`